# Power consumption in Raspberry pi zero w

Tags: python, power-saving, raspberry-pi-zero

I am using Raspberry Pi zero w for my project which is going to be operated on 2600mah battery. Pi is interfaced with CSI camera, Telit GPS, ADC. Also configured Pi as Access Point and BLE peripheral.

All these things are controlled through BLE android application. Camera takes a photo and GPS gives location when particular switch pressed from BLE application.

I don't know at which interval location tracking is needed, it depends on User. So, I am switching GPS in sleep mode and full power mode to save the power consumption.

When BLE application is connected, GPS is in sleep mode, battery level is monitoring continuously it consumes 180 to 210 mA.

How can I reduce the power consumption for optimum battery usage?

From some articles on the RPi power consumption, It should consume approximately 100 mA or even less. Is it possible to achieve this level for my application?

Comment: I suppose I'd start by disconnecting/disabling everything and measuring consumption to create some benchmarks... and checking for stray processes that you might be able to tune/disable. Then I'd reintroduce one device at a time, and remeasure consumption to try to isolate the issue... perhaps checking the manufacturers specs to see if each device can be tuned. I would also disconnect the battery and measure it's loss rate with nothing connected.

Comment: Thanks @brennan. I have no any other peripheral enabled like hdmi or USB except above mentioned. And about stray processes, How can I tune/disable these processes?

Comment: I would try [powertop](https://superuser.com/questions/318432/power-optimization-in-linux)

Comment: There is another good thread on [raspberrypi stackexchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/2137)